# Why are parallelizable tasks emberrassing?

Tags: adjectives, computing, software

Software developers often speak of "emberassingly parallel" tasks. Why is this adjective used in this phrase? What makes parallel tasks emberassing?

Comment: This is less about the usage of the English language or the adjective, but rather an opinion of something from a subject-specific field. To answer such a question one would have to know what parallel tasks are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83677/what-is-embarrassing-about-an-embarrassingly-parallel-proble. Also some kind of research, such as why are "embarrassingly parallel tasks" embarrassing, could of led you to that answer.

Comment: This question better asked on one of the #Computer SE sites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "embarrassing" about an embarrassingly parallel problem?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83677/what-is-embarrassing-about-an-embarrassingly-parallel-problem)

Comment: Yes, this is a dupe and can be closed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if something is embarrassingly easy, it is ridiculously easy, so much so that when you do it it feels like you are showing off.

> In parallel computing, an embarrassingly parallel workload or problem
>   (also called perfectly parallel or pleasingly parallel) is one where
>   little or no effort is needed to separate the problem into a number of
>   parallel tasks.
>
> "Embarrassingly" is used here in the same sense as in the phrase "an
>   embarrassment of riches", meaning an overabundance—here referring to
>   parallelization problems which are "embarrassingly easy"
>
> An alternative term, pleasingly parallel, has gained some use, perhaps
>   to avoid the negative connotations of embarrassment in favor of a
>   positive reflection on the parallelizability of the problems: "Of
>   course, there is nothing embarrassing about these programs at all.

[Embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)

---

> an embarrassment of riches formal ​ so many good things or people that
>   it is impossible to decide which of them you want

[Embarrassment of riches](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/an-embarrassment-of-riches)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarvey! With riches, embarrassment seems more intuitive to me--one might genuinely be embarrassed of one's inheritance or successes. But I can't see any sense in which one might be embarrassed of the degree to which a problem can be executed in parallel. It still seems an odd usage of the language to me...

Comment: "an embarrassment of children"